# How to set multiple conditional rule on webform registration?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

I am trying to setup an event page on webform with 4 Radio button labeled How many people would like to register - 1, 2 , 3, 4 and 4 contacts field set contact1, contact2, contact3, contact4

What I am trying to achieve, if I select

- Radio 1 - Contact1 field set would show
- Radio 2 - Contact1 & Contact2 would Show
- Radio 3 - Contact1, 2 & 3 show
- Radio 4 - all field set should show.

I am just cant get it to work and keep getting this error and cant go past enabling 2 people.

```
    Conditional errors on page 1:
More than one conditional hides or shows component "Contact2".
More than one conditional hides or shows component "Contact3".
```

Would anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably pretty close. May just need to reverse your logic. You haven't provided screenshot of your Conditionals. On a site we have this I see this in Conditionals

[image]
and
[image]
etc

Comment: Spot on!! Many Thanks for sharing..